# Facebook login using PHP then redirect to URL with get args

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, get

I am trying to make a Facebook login in my website, I have faced a problems.

I have used [this](http://dan.cx/blog/2010/09/integrating-facebook-logins-into-your-php-website-easily) class to use Facebook login in PHP.

I have created a PHP file in my site called `login.php` which contain the following code

```
$facebook = new FacebookLogin(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);
$user = $facebook->doLogin();
// then initialize the SESSION variables here using $user info
header("Location: ' . $url);
```

The problem now, is that I want to pass get arguments to the `login.php` and from this argument I can know the $url which I will redirect to. But the `FacebookLogin` class is making a redirect call so the get argument in login.php is lost, so I have decided to add the login.php argument to `$this->url` in the `FacebookLogin` constructor with this line:

```
$this->my_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

The problem now is that this is not working too as in the `verifyLogin()` , this line is returning empty result as the URL is not correct:

```
$result = @file_get_contents(self::TOKEN_URL . '?' . http_build_query($data));
```

and it was supposed to return the `access_token`

So what do you think?

Simply I need a way that the user click a link to login by Facebook but before returning to the user, I want to pass by my code in PHP then redirect to a url that was specified by the user click in the get arguments.

I'm sorry, it may be silly but I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem and have a deadline after few hours.

Appreciate your help

Comment: You could store the redirect URL as a session variable. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but when I try to access it again, it was not found!!

Comment: I have searched and found that the storing session variables before redirect is not working!

Comment: Is the domain you redirect to after login, the same as that in which the login page exists?

Comment: No, actually the scenario is as follows:
At page http://www.foo.com there is login link with url="http://www.bar.com/login.php?next_uri=http://www.foo.com"

So when user click I want in login.php store the $_GET['next_uri'] in any way then do the facebook login, and return back to login.php to store some session variables then redirect to the next_uri value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you try to achieve is simple with usage of [PHP-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret'=> 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
));

$loginURL = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  //'redirect_uri'=>'URL_WHERE_USER_WILL_BE_LANDED_AFTER_LOGIN' 
));

header("Location: {$loginURL}");
```

If you wish to pass some data to your application for later step than user came back authorized, pass that as parts of URL arguments for URL provided in `redirect_uri` parameter of `getLoginUrl`.

So if for example you will pass `http://my.app.com/?link_to_visit=some_link` as `redirect_url` you will be redirected to that URL instead of current URL (before authorization).

Later you can just:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret'=> 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
));

$userId = $facebook->getUser();
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$linkToVisit = $_REQUEST['link_to_visit'];
```

**BTW**, for the sake of humanity don't use some silly client written by someone with unknown reputation before couple of years in favor of Official Facebook PHP-SDK that do follow all changes (and they are huge) in platform...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I have understood what you mean, but after doing it, I have received an error "This webpage has a redirect loop" ... actually I have made 2 files as you said, the first code snippet in file tmp_login.php and the next url = 'http://localhost/handle_login.php?next_uri=http://www.foobar.com'

Then the second code snippet in the handle_login.php file, but after redirecting the $loginURL I receive this error before reaching to handle_login.php

Thanks a lot

Comment: That's OK now, I have checked the getLoginUrl() docs and found that it is 'redirect_uri' not 'next'
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/
Thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: I'm sorry, but when the handle_job.php is executed the $facebook->getUser() is always returning 0 !!